Slow NVMe (Gen4) on Ubuntu
For the new Ubuntu 24.04 release, i bought a new WD_Black SN770 NVMe, which is advertised as up to 5150MB/s (GEN4).
My motherboard (ASrock X570 Pro4) supports Gen4x4 and according to LinkSta (LnkSta:   Speed 16GT/s, Width x4) everything should be OK.
But if i perform a test, i get way less speed:
hdparm -t /dev/nvme0n1
    /dev/nvme0n1:
     Timing buffered disk reads: 8840 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2946.04 MB/sec

So what could be wrong in my system? Why dont i get ~5GB/s? In another thread, it was said to be a problem with the "barrier-flag", but it did not solve my issue.


Do you have latest firmware for both UEFI and SSD? Compare to vendor's site: sudo lshw | grep -m 1 -A 5 "*-firmware" &
udisksctl status or sudo nvme list

There was an update available for the storage, but it didn't change anything. Still the same speed.

Can you try FIO and rsync real test? We have same issue, where hdparm show approximatelly 3000MB/s, but FIO 7000MB/s
fio --ioengine=libaio --name=io --rw=read --direct=1 --numjobs=1 --bs=256k --iodepth=128 --ramp_time=15 --runtime=10 --filename=/dev/YOURDISK We wrote about this issue here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515338/nvme-gen4-disks-running-slow-in-real-world-usage-rsync

Even though the hdparm test is designed for minimum overhead, I think the test results are still system and CPU limited.
I have two NVME drives installed in my Ubuntu 24.04 test server. Both are WD Black SN850X, with a sequential read specification of 7300 MB/Sec. One is 1TB and one is 2TB.
I get:
doug@s19:/media/nvme/home/doug/c$ sudo taskset -c 6 hdparm -t /dev/nvme0n1

/dev/nvme0n1:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 5070 MB in  3.00 seconds = 1689.66 MB/sec
doug@s19:/media/nvme/home/doug/c$ sudo taskset -c 6 hdparm -t /dev/nvme1n1

/dev/nvme1n1:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 7718 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2572.02 MB/sec

But with a top capture at the same time, observe CPU 6 has no idle time, and seems system limited. We expect a high level of IO wait time, as observed.
top - 08:27:01 up 2 days,  1:34,  2 users,  load average: 0.12, 0.04, 0.01
Tasks: 212 total,   3 running, 209 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  :  1.0 us, 38.4 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id, 60.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu8  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu10 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  31924.4 total,   4513.2 free,    858.0 used,  27021.1 buff/cache

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   5506 root      20   0    4860   4736   2304 R  39.0   0.0   0:00.67 hdparm
      1 root      20   0   22256  12392   9064 S   0.0   0.0   0:01.83 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 kthreadd
      3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 pool_wo+
...

If what I say is true, then the test results should be CPU maximum frequency dependent:
Max-Freq Results         %
100%     2590.10 MB/sec
 90%     2544.17 MB/sec   -1.77%
 80%     2531.59 MB/sec   -2.26%
 70%     2492.58 MB/sec   -3.77%
 60%     2423.82 MB/sec   -6.42%
 50%     2305.09 MB/sec  -11.00%

