NVMe gen4 disks running slow in real world usage (rsync)
We have big difference between FIO tests and "real" speed via rsync for example.
We are facing this problem on U.2 gen4 and M.2 gen4 + adapter as well. Totally same results for both. U.2 is direcly connected to backplane.
Results:
FIO - 7000MB/s
RSync - 1000-1500MB/s (we tested 10GB file with zeros inside, same results for "dd")
Manufacturer: Supermicro
Set: SuperServer SYS-120H-TNR
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, with latest packages
Motherboard: X12DHM-6 (1.02A)
Filesystem: ext4
BIOS: latest
Kernel: 5.15
CPU: 2x Intel Xeon Silver 4316, 3.4GHz, 20 cores, 40 threads
RAM: 2TB (32*64 3200 Mhz Samsung DDR4)
Disks:
M.2 disk KC3000 + Fury Renegade, both with gen4 adapter. U.2 disk Intel (Solidigm) D7-P5500. Disk firmware is latest
Raid1(LVM), but without raid/LVM its similar. Booting to sysrescue CD is with same results.
Server is idle. No problem with temperature or something else. Disk smart is OK. Replacement of disk same results.
Bios reset do default - same.
U.2 disk is 100% gen working, because:
lspci | grep -i nvme
e4:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation NVMe DC SSD [3DNAND, Sentinel Rock Controller]

lspci -vv -s e4:00.0 | grep -w LnkCap
LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 16GT/s, Width x4, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <16us

Any suggestions what to test and how to discover where is problem?
Thank you.
EDIT: 2024-05-27:
I think, it's normal behaviour unfortunatelly, we had exaggerated expectations from nvme :(
https://www.guru3d.com/review/kingston-kc3000-pcie-4-m-2-nvme-review/page-6/

Search this site for "slow copy".  Lots of specific problems, but the no-obvious-cause cases probably resolve to a faster read than write filling up system buffers and dragging the system to a crawl.

@ubfan1: We already googled this problem and this forum, but we don't found any reason/solution. We have this problem from beginning (X months). :(

You have been stepped on by the elephant in the room (that nobody wants to talk about).  This site has many suggestions for specific cases: nocache will cut out read buffering (saving buffer space), varous dirty-bytes or rations to trigger flushing, change scheduling type, user space buffers,... etc. Even just adding more memory helps. The acutal write is given to the system, so is not even process related!

We already tried a lot ot things and tips, before we post this. I personally read more than 100 topics about similar problems, but nothing help us. Results are still same. We have 2TB memory, 16*64GB, its a lot.

Impressive hardware. If your free memory drops significantly during a copy (I assume your copied file is larger than your memory), you might have to write your own copy program which limits the reads to some fraction of the writes (make it adjustable so you can find the sweet spot).

@ubfan1: We tested for example 100GB file rsync or 10GB file rsync, still same. Size of file makes no difference.
Program makes no difference as well (rsync same, dd same, cp same, everything same)

Both those files are a tiny fraction of your 2TB memory.  If you system buffers fill up, your copy speed will be 100-1000+ times slower. What you see may just be the max you can get when actually allocating memory, doing kernel stuff, etc. You can try increasing user buffers on copy programs like tar and cpio to maybe reduce memory trashing.

You may answer your own question, and accept it after a bit, helping others and gaining some reputation points.

@ubfan1 I think, it's normal behaviour unfortunatelly, we had exaggerated expectations from nvme :( https://www.guru3d.com/review/kingston-kc3000-pcie-4-m-2-nvme-review/page-6/
